# Asp.Net SqlDataReader value magically turns into null on attempt to access and use it

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nullreferenceexception, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have an sql command that depends on the results of other sql commands. There are five sql commands in this chain, but the problem occurs in the 4th.

The 5th command must save data to the archive table. When it has to run and take the **completion_date** value from the 4th command, it throws a null reference exception. Actually it says, that **Reader4[0]** can't be read because it has null value. That's wrong because it has value, because in the database these queries work fine and also because the condition **if (Reader4.HasRows == true)** is true, it means that **WHERE** statement is true in the 4th command, which also includes checking the **completion_date**! What's wrong with this asp.net?

```
Command4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT trade_date FROM Schedule WHERE traider_id=@traiderID AND good_id=@goodID AND position_id=@positionID AND status_id=1 AND completion_date IS NOT NULL", Connection4); //note the completion_date check
Command4.Parameters.Add("@traiderID", Convert.ToInt32(Reader3[0]));
Command4.Parameters.Add("@positionID", CurrentPosition);
Command4.Parameters.Add("@goodID", Convert.ToInt32(Reader1[0]));
Reader4 = Command4.ExecuteReader();
if (Reader4.HasRows == true) //this check is done successfully
{
    Command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Archive (traider_id, good_id, completion_date) VALUES (@traiderID, @goodID, @completionDate)", Connection5);
    Command5.Parameters.Add("@traiderID", Convert.ToInt32(Reader3[0]));
    Command5.Parameters.Add("@goodID", Convert.ToInt32(Reader1[0]));
    Command5.Parameters.Add("@completionDate", Convert.ToDateTime(Reader4[0])); //Here is the problem
    Command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Reader4.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you startin to read from the `reader`?

i.e. where do you call

```
 Reader4.Read();
```

after

```
Reader4 = Command4.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: No problem. I find the cause of mistakes like this is large blocks of code. Try to split up more.